# Why would adding a form in one cell of a table disable a button in another row/another cell?

Tags: jsp

OK, my title is a bit confusing. But here goes. I've been trying to fix this since yesterday. I have this table. It has 3 columns, and as many rows as can be added by the user. I have been assigned to switch out the buttons on the page with ones that didn't have parameters in the URL's, and have successfully done that by creating post forms with hidden fields that submit and take the user to the next page.

One of these forms is in the third column of each row, and worked perfectly with each added row.  However, after I added the form into the  tag the add button will no longer click, and add a row. I have tried numerous things, and discovered that if I move the code into one column and create it as a post form it will click, but won't create a row. If I move the entire row to the top (which doesn't make sense) it still works perfectly.

I should clarify the form that causes the effect is near the top, and the submit button is the one around line 35.

I have posted the code below. If anyone can possibly point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```
                    <td class="centerMe" headers="actionEdit">
                                        <c:if test="${action == 'addIt'}">
                                            <form action="editPage" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id1" name="id1" value="${something.somethingId}" />
                    <input type= "image" img src="${contextPath}/img/edit_d1.gif" alt="Paper and pen icon. Edit ${something.somethingId}" title="Edit ${something.somethingId}"/>
                                            </form>
                                        </c:if>
                                        <c:if test="${action == 'edit'}">
                                            <c:if test="${something.somethingId == somethingId}">
                                                <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('form');">
                                                    <img src="${contextPath}/img/save_d1.gif" onclick="submitForm('form1');" alt="Disk icon. Savechange" title="Save change"/>
                                                </a>

                                                <spring:url var="url" value="${servletPath}/adminCancel"/>
                                                <a href="${url}" onclick="cancelled();">
                                                    <img src="${contextPath}/img/cancel_d1.gif" alt="Opposite arrows icon. Cancel change." title="Cancelchange" />
                                                </a>    
                                            </c:if>
                                        </c:if>    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                            <c:if test="${action == 'add'}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="CenterMe">
                                        <form:hidden path="somethingId" value="${somethingBean.nextSomethingId}"/>
                                        ${somethingBean.nextSomethingId}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="LeftMe" >
                                        <form:input path="description" class="inputTight" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" title="Enter a new  Description for Id ${somethingBean.nextSomethingId}"/>
                                        <br/>
                                        <form:errors path="description" class="errorText" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="CenterMe">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="inputTight" title="Add new Id to Supported list"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:if> </form>
```